# How to rewrite directory name to base url of a wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am working on a wordpress project where i have my project in cpanel file manager

like: /var/www/public_html/myProject

so right now i am accessing this using below url

like: mysites.com/myProject

so i want to access my myProject directory using only my base url that means whenever a user type: mysites.com it should be point to mysites.com but actually page should be display from mysites.com/myProject.

in other cases like

mysites.com/myProject/productList

should be point to 
mysites.com/productList

but mysites.com/productList should comes from mysites.com/myProject/productList.

Hope you have understand my question

i think there might be setting in htaccess but i need some help of you to achive it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this `.htaccess`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?mysites.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/myProject/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /myProject/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?mysites.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ myProject/index.php [L] 
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score -1):

Just copy all the files and folders from `myProject` folder and paste it to `public_html`. Now all the WorPress files and folders will be in your `public_html` folder. You can access the site using base url.

Comment: you are right @eliza but we don't want to do this. that is the main problem.